# Unable to start my lenovo laptop

Tags: windows-8, hardware-failure

The other night after using my laptop I turned it off. When I woke up in the morning and tried to start it, it would not get started. 
So as a solution i tried some online tips but i still could not get it started.
Any leads on this would be helpful.
Can anyone tell me what could be the possible problem.? thank you.
Edit:
It does not power on.
I have tried removing the battery, plugging in the power cord to turn on and   then turning off by holding the power button down and trying again.

Comment: Can you be more specific? 'it could not get started' could mean practically anything. Does the laptop powers on? You get a message while booting up?

Comment: yeah. its not getting power on.

Comment: Is it plugged in when you attempt this? Does it have a removable battery?if so take battery out

Comment: @Dave yeah. i did your above step. removed the battery , plugged in to power socket and held the button for over 1 min.

Comment: So you removed battery, plugged the laptop in (still no battery) and it won't turn on?

Comment: @Dave yes. exactly. it didn't turn on.

Comment: @Praveen Raikar, sorry but no power means no lights, not able to get into bios, the power point switch is on, can you test the power cable on another computer? Your data should be safe and you may be able to remove it from this computer and place in another to test that the drive is still all ok. It may be your PSU that needs testing?

Answer (score 1):

Step through this process, stopping whenever you finally get it to boot:

1. Remove the battery and power up using the DC adapter only without the battery plugged in. If this works replace the battery.
2. Power up using a full battery without the adapter plugged in. If this works, replace the DC adapter.
3. Observe after you press the power button - is the hard drive spinning? Are any lights powering on? Are there any fans or other signs of any electric activity anywhere in the laptop? If not, it is dead at the power button assembly, the motherboard, or the power plug assembly, which may also be part of the motherboard. Remove the cover and check the power button assembly for signs of corrosion or damage to the button assembly that might prevent it from creating an electrical circuit on its contacts. If nothing is found, replace power plug assembly. If part of motherboard or still no power-on, replace motherboard.
4. Bring the laptop into an extremely dark environment and turn it on. Once you hear the drive spinning up, shine a very bright flashlight at an angle into the screen. If you can see a ghostly image of the POST or login screen of your laptop, then you need to replace the screen backlight.
5. While powered on, attach a second screen and use the correct function key on the laptop keyboard to toggle displays. If you are able to get a visual here, the inverter for the laptop display needs to be replaced. If not, the GPU on the CPU or motherboard is dead, or the RAM is dead. Replace the CPU unless soldered to the motherboard. Otherwise, replace the RAM. If the problem persists after both CPU and RAM have been replaced, replace the motherboard.

Comment: I took the laptop to repair shop. they told me that power ic and display ic is damaged.

Comment: Wow, two at once. Unlikely, but they are probably covering their bases. Tell them to replaced  just the power converter first unless it would be more expensive that way

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you've verified that the charger itself is still working and that the issue is not as simple as the laptop has a flat battery. If so then it appears as if some internal hardware is bust. Which is it? I don't think we can tell with out looking at the laptop.

The solution is to take it to a PC repair shop, or send back to the manufacturer.